# Exactly One Temporal Window is Expected

Tags: sql, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm getting this error message when configuring my streaming analytics query into my event hub. I'm trying to query for real time data as it arrives into the event hub, so I removed the windowing grouping. I suspect this is what causes this error message and won't allow the query to be used. But is there anyway to get true real time data from an event hub or is it only pseudo through use of the windowing system which can allow for multiple events to occur in one window of time?

Here's my query for reference:

```
SELECT month(system.timestamp) as month, system.timestamp as time, city, state, zip, hascontactedconsultant, websiteguideid, status, assignedto, 
type, count(type)
INTO ttvleadsstream
FROM ttvhuball
TIMESTAMP BY time
GROUP BY month, time, city, state, zip, hascontactedconsultant, websiteguideid, status, assignedto, type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a group by in your query, you have to provide a time window over which to group the events by. It is mandatory. Output will be produced once every "window".

If you don't have a group by, then events are sent to output source as and when it arrives.

Can you describe the expected behavior with example data?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see now that without an aggregate function in the select list, the streaming analytics job pulls all data as it becomes available in the event hub.

Comment: As per Stream Analytics documentation on MSDN, Either <window_type> or System.Timestamp is required, <group by item> is optional. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835023.aspx 

So you need to specify a windowing function